# How to upgrade jQuery Mobile Splitview?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-website, splitview

I have an old jQuery Mobile Splitview app and need to hide the menu on the left.

Updated:
In Chrome view app at localhost and enter inspect menu to view the phone view: It's landing page is OK which shown content and menu folded properly.
Until I login or click menu to enter any submenu. The menu is gone and I have to use phone back or forward instead.

[image]

My question is

1. How to hide the left menu (if still using splitview)?
2. Or is there anything to replace it as [jQuery Mobile Splitview](http://asyraf9.github.io/jquerymobile-splitview/) hasn't had activity for 5 years. Seems to have no support with others anymore.

   Picture of landing page look good in localhost view through Chrome.
   [image]

But when uploaded to heroku it only showed menu until we click home.
[image]

And below I believed was the code about this issue.

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1")
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = render :partial => "layouts/metatag"
    - if GMAP
      = javascript_include_tag "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
  %body
    = render :partial => "mindapp/menu"
    %div{"data-id" => "main", "data-role" => "panel", "data-backbtn"=>"false"}
      - if @cache
        - cache = {}
      - else
        - cache = {"data-cache"=>"never"}
      - if @backbtn
        - backbtn= {"data-backbtn"=>"true"}
      - else
        - backbtn= {"data-backbtn"=>"false"}
      %div{{"data-role" => "page"}.merge(cache) }
        %div{{"data-role" => "header"}.merge(backbtn)}
          %h1= @title || DEFAULT_TITLE
        %div{"data-role" => "content"}
          = yield
      = render :partial => "mindapp/static"
:javascript
  $(document).on("pagehide", 'div', function(e,ui) {
    var page = $(e.target);
    if(page.attr('data-cache') == 'never') {
      page.remove();
    };
  });
  $( document ).on( "pagechange", function(){
    $.get("/mindapp/ajax_notice", function(r) {$(r).appendTo('head').remove()});
    var meta = $(".content").text();
    if (!meta) {
      meta = "Mindapp Tools to create visual programming using mindmap"
    }
    $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', meta);
  });
/= raw handle_ma_notice
```

Comment: you should use a Panel, where the page content is responsive. [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6Cnn/38/)

Comment: Ok Will try Thk

Answer (score 0):

It's seem the viewport don't work unless I moved it to have it refreshed in partial file.
In mycase I have all metatag in _metatag.html.erb, then worked.

Still I have another feature that need to be resolved. How to hide the left menu and make content 100%.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="follow, all" />
  <meta name="language" content="en, th" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1">
```